# Correlation length and renormalization group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

In [Scaling and Renormalization in Statistical Physics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/scaling-and-renormalization-in-statistical-physics/924C0B0D39123F681CF3353C42E5E836) there's following block of information:

[image]

I have some misunderstanding of some ideas.

**1) How to define correlation length for arbitrary theory?**

I understand, that asymptotically for free massive theory correlation length have form:

$$
\langle \phi(x) \phi(y) \rangle \sim e^{-r/\xi}/r^{d-2}
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
\xi\sim 1/m
$$

But what with interacting theory? I think, that it is possible, to have another form of correlator.

**2) Why correlation length only scale $\xi \to \xi/b$?** For example in $\phi^4$ theory, mass  have more complicated transformation law:

$$
m^2 \to b^2(m^2+ag)
$$

How this fact agree with $\xi\sim 1/m$?

Comment: Your first question has been addressed many times on this site. Search for *correlation length*.